# When SSL detect a replay attack?

Tags: tls, attacks, rsa, client, replay-detection

Suppose an attacker records all messages of a SSL handshake (RSA one-way), and starts a replay attack. When (after which message) can the server possibly detect the attack?

Now suppose the attacker changes strategy, and sends the first three phases (up to the session key exchange), but sends this sequence many times. Why would an attacker do this, and what would be the impact on the server?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last question? It's not clear what you're asking there.

Comment: Ok,I have made a error.The attacker change strategy and send to server the messages of the fist-three phases(until at the message client-key-exchange) the attacker send these messages more times.What is the purpose of the attacker?i.e what is the attacker searching to made?What are the consequences?

Comment: Consequences to who or what? To the attacker? To the server?

Comment: To the server!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an attacker replays old handshake messages, the trickery will become apparent with the `Finished` message from the attacker, because the message previously recorded was encrypted and MACed with distinct keys, and its contents won't match either:

- The derivation from the master secret (resulting from the key exchange mechanism, e.g. RSA) into symmetric encryption and MAC keys involves the `client_random` and `server_random` from the two "hello" messages; the attacker replayed one of these values (e.g. the `client_random` if the attacker is replaying the *client* messages) but the other is from the peer, and is distinct from what was recorded.
- The contents of the `Finished` messages are a hash computed over all the previous handshake messages, including the two "hello" messages, and thus, again, one of the "randoms" has changed and the hash won't match.

**Note:** if the server requires certificate-based client authentication, and the attacker is replaying the client part of the exchange, then the replay will get detected earlier, at the `CertificateVerify` message: the recorded handshake message is a signature (by the genuine client) computed over a hash of all previous handshake messages, including, again, the two "randoms". However, SSL server who ask for client certificates are relatively rare.

---

An attacker who begins but never finishes handshakes is doing a [Denial-of-Service attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack): he makes the server allocate resources and spend CPU cycles for nothing. Typically, the attacker would send a `ClientHello` claiming support of only "DHE" cipher suites; then, the server must respond with a sequence of messages, including a `ServerKeyExchange` message which necessarily involves a newly computed signature. The CPU cost for the attacker is minimal (only the effort of opening a TCP connection and sending a few bytes) while the server must do some cryptography.

Since that kind of DoS requires doing an actual TCP connection, the attacker's IP address is revealed; also, signatures are not *that* expensive: a PC can do thousands of signatures per second. Therefore, SSL-based DoS are usually done by botnets.